# Hibernate cannot create a database with case sensitivity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I would like to establish a schema and generate tables within it. For this purpose, I have the following code.

```java
@Table(name = "credential", schema = "BTA", indexes = @Index(columnList = "neighborhood"))
```

I consistently encounter issues during table creation. Whenever tables are being created, it produces the following error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema "bta" does not exist
```

"I included the lines `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` and `org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` in my application.yml file. Despite this, none of them resolved the issue. I aim to create a 'credential' table under the 'BTA' schema."

PostgreSQL version: 15

Comment: Minor advice: Don't even try and use only lower case for object names.

Comment: I think `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` takes your identifiers as they are, unaltered and passes that to the db. [There, folding unquoted `BTA` regardless of case to lowercase `bta` is standard Postgres behaviour](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Specify it as `schema = "\"BTA\""` to let the double-quotes through and preserve the case.

Comment: @FrankHeikens what might be the problem in the future?

Comment: @Zegarek I have tried that before but it doesn't work

Comment: All the double quotes " that you must use forever. Every future change in your code, will most likely have one or more bugs related to this. Over and over again.